# Error in building crossroads for roads

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, shapely

I was trying to split the raw road data into segments. First I created road_segments table.Then I convert the contents of roads table into series of connected road segments using shapely.

For each road, I start by loading the road's name and geometry into memory.

The code upto here works correctly.

I got the road's LineString geometry , I want to split at each point where it touches or crosses another road. For this, I try to build a list of cross roads for this road.

```
 crossroads = []
 cursor.execute("SELECT ST_AsText(centerline) FROM ROADS" +
                   "WHERE ST_Touches(roads.centerline, " +
                   "ST_GeomFromText(%s)) OR ST_Crosses(" +
                   "roads.centerline, ST_GeomFromText(%s))",
                   (wkt, wkt))
  for row in cursor:
        crossroad = shapely.wkt.loads(row[0])
        crossroads.append(crossroad)
```

But the follwing error comes:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-0d71c4db883b> in <module>()
      4                    "ST_GeomFromText(%s)) OR ST_Crosses(" +
      5                    "roads.centerline, ST_GeomFromText(%s))",
----> 6                    (wkt, wkt))

ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: ...sText(centerline) FROM ROADSWHERE ST_Touches(roads.centerlin...
```

When I edited the code as below:

```
crossroads = []
cursor.execute("SELECT ST_AsText(centerline) FROM ROADS WHERE ST_Touches(roads.centerline, " +
                   "ST_GeomFromText(%s)) OR ST_Crosses(" +
                   "roads.centerline, ST_GeomFromText(%s))",
                   (wkt, wkt))
for row in cursor:
    crossroad = shapely.wkt.loads(row[0])
    crossroads.append(crossroad)
```

Following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-b50bc9a8488c> in <module>()
      3                    "ST_GeomFromText(%s)) OR ST_Crosses(" +
      4                    "roads.centerline, ST_GeomFromText(%s))",
----> 5                    (wkt, wkt))
      6 for row in cursor:
      7     crossroad = shapely.wkt.loads(row[0])

InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be a space between `FROM ROADS` and `WHERE ST_Touches`?

Comment: Yes ..Space is supposed.

Comment: Is your table very big? I had a similar problem with a huge table and a misconfigured postgres installation

Comment: Yeah table is large ..I edited the code as below and it worked:
crossroads = []
cursor.execute('SELECT ST_AsText(centerline) FROM ROADS WHERE ST_Touches(roads.centerline,ST_GeomFromText(%s)) OR ST_Crosses(roads.centerline,ST_GeomFromText(%s))',
                   (wkt, wkt))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is because there is no space between "ROADSWHERE", and the second InternalError is because the transaction needs to be rolled back, i.e. `conn.rollback()`.

Firstly, WKB is a faster lossless way of transferring geometry between PostGIS and Shapely. You can get this from shapely geometries with the `.wkb_hex` property, and from PostGIS without doing anything special. And secondly, I find it is best to write SQL expressions using triple quotes, like this:

```
from shapely import wkb
cursor.execute("""\
SELECT centerline FROM ROADS
WHERE ST_Touches(roads.centerline, %(geom)s)
   OR ST_Crosses(roads.centerline, %(geom)s;
""", {'geom': geom.wkb_hex})
for row in cursor:
    crossroad = wkb.loads(row[0], hex=True)
    crossroads.append(crossroad)
```

Lastly, I'm not sure if it helps, but to better understand how predicate operators like "Touches" and "Crosses" work, you may want to see [DE-9IM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM). You can make custom predicates with [ST_Relate](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Relate.html), rather than calling two different predicates.